# MongoDB Atlas nested group LDAP

Tags: mongodb, active-directory, ldap, mongodb-atlas

i'm getting a problem with mongodb atlas and nested group on active directory.

At the moment we don't have problem with user into a group:

GROUP -> USER1

If this user, for example, is nested inside other group:

GROUp -> GROUP1 -> USER1

we can connect on mongodb atlas with "user1" but it doesn't show anything, i mean collection or db which "group" has permission.

At the moment ldap query template on our mongo atlas portal is:

{USER}?memberOf?base

[image]

i think that it not work recursively and list only member of the group. I found on mongodb doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/authenticate-nativeldap-activedirectory/#configure-ldap-query-template-for-authorization

this:

```
security:
  ldap:
    authz:
      queryTemplate:
        "DC=example,DC=com??sub?(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={USER}))"
```

so i think is possible to build a query that work recursively.

How i have to build the query to change the one of the image attached, to get user inside nested group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use exactly what they have in their documentation:

```
DC=example,DC=com??sub?(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={USER}))
```

Just change `DC=example,DC=com` to the distinguished name (DN) of your domain.

LDAP queries has several parts, each separated by a `?`.

1. The search root. This is the DN where you want the search to start.
2. A list of attributes you want the search to return. This is why `memberOf` is specified in the default search.
3. The search depth. This can be one of:

   - Subtree (or "sub"), meaning that you want to search all levels in the directory below the search root.
   - One level. If the search root is an OU, for example, then using "one level" means you only want to search that one OU and not anything below it.
   - Base, meaning that the results can only include the search root itself.
4. The search query.

So in the default query:

```
{USER}?memberOf?base
```

The search root is `{USER}`, the DN of the authenticated user. It returns only the `memberOf` attribute. And you only want to look at that one object (because of "base"). There is no search query.

In the new query:

```
DC=example,DC=com??sub?(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={USER}))
```

The search root is the root of the domain. There is no list of attributes. The search depth is "sub", meaning you want it to search the whole domain. Then the search query tells it to return all groups that have the authenticated user as a direct or nested member.

In both queries, you end up with a list of groups.

Comment: Hi, i tried to substitute, from MongoAtlas portal, {USER}?memberOf?base with DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com??sub?(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={USER}))  (i tried also DC=mydomain,DC=com??sub?(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={USER})) and ??sub?(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={USER})) ) but i'm getting error:
    
We were unable to verify your server connection. Please check your settings and try again.

The new query have to be formatted in a different way?

Comment: Was it working before with `{USER}?memberOf?base`? That sounds like it can't connect to your AD server. Is the [servers setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/authenticate-nativeldap-activedirectory/#configure-mongodb-to-connect-to-active-directory) correct?

Comment: yes all is working fine (it was already configured) with {USER}?memberOf?base without problem

Comment: yes is correct. I tried with both DC=corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com and only DC=mydomain,DC=com but i got same error